# How to use two different collection in CompositeView

Tags: marionette

I am new to Marionette.
I am trying to create a view in which I need to show a dropdown and a table.
Dropdown is rendered from a collection. and based on value selected in dropdown I need to render collection in table.

Can you please tell me how can I achieve this kind of view ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried to achieve this thing like

http://jsfiddle.net/H8AZY/17/

```
var compositeView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template : Handlebars.compile($("#sample-template").html()),
    itemView: itemview,
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',
    templateHelpers: function(){
        var helpers = {};
        console.log(this.coll.models);
        helpers.users = this.coll.models;
        return helpers;
    },
    triggers: {
    'change select': 'selectName'
    },
    ui:{
        select: 'select'
    },
    onSelectName: function() {
        console.log(this.ui.select.val());
        var newModel = this.coll.findWhere({name: this.ui.select.val()});   
        //this.collection = new Backbone.Collection(newModel.get('res'));
       this.collection.reset(newModel.get('res'));
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.coll = options.coll;
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    }
});
```

Is it a good way to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways you can accomplish this.

You can just create the DOM manually.

```
class MyCompositeView extends Marionette.CompositeView
  ui:
    "select" : "select.my-select"
  onRender: ->
    _.each @options.states, (state) =>
      $option = $("<option>", { id: state.id, 
                                value: state.get("name") })
      this.ui.select.append($option)

view = new MyCompositeView({collection: this.collection, states: stateCollection });
```

OR you can create an entire CollectionView for your select:

```
class StateView extends Marionette.ItemView
  tagName: "option"

class StateCollectionView extends Marionette.CollectionView
  tagName: "select"
  itemView: StateView
```

Comment: Actually I am able to manipulate drop down list from collection. But I also want to show another collection in table below drop down based on selected value in dropdown. So what will be a good way to do that ?